# Access a browser inside tabpage

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

I programmatically added a web browser control to a tab page using:

```
var webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
```

and added 2 more in other tab pages.

Now I want to access the web browser in tab page 1 to send the browser to a website, but I don't know how to access the browser that I just created.

Here is part of the code that adds the browser:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Browser " + tabControl1.TabCount);
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = x;

var browser = new WebBrowser();

browser.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
browser.Visible = true;
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: `                tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Browser " + tabControl1.TabCount);
                tabControl1.SelectedIndex = x;
                var browser = new WebBrowser();
                browser.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
                browser.Visible = true;
                browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: There's no good reason to lose track of the control reference.  A simple workaround is to add it to a `List<WebBrowser>` so you can always find it back.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Url property of the WebBrowser instance to set the page.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
browser.Url = New Uri("http://www.example.com");
```